# Accidentally installed BIOS/MBR on GPT/UEFI

Tags: arch-linux, gpt, mbr

Quite some time ago, I installed a Linux system on my moms laptop. And just recently I noticed I have installed and partitioned (with fdisk) a BIOS/MBR on a system, that already has UEFI.

The machine now has dual boot Windows 7 and Arch Linux and it seems to be working just fine. I wouldn't even have noticed, if I haven't checked `dmesg` and that there are some errors in it, then I finally checked the partition table...and got shocked (I really didn't expect that at the time, It was my first installation on a UEFI machine).

Did anyone had the same experience here? What are the consequences leaving this unfixed? And is there a way to fix this, without reinstalling everything?

Comment: How did you "install" BIOS/MBR on a GPT partition table without overwriting it?

Comment: @sikerbela I really have no idea, but I know I used `fdisk` (which I think is supposed to be used for partitioning MBR) without any warnings or errors, which I also find strange..

Comment: Weird... man fdisk says it does not understand GPT. Now I am curious about what happens when you partition GPT with fdisk too.